# Javascript detect display monitors connected to a PC

Tags: javascript

My question may sound a bit silly, but is important for my work - suppose I have a web application running javascript on my PC. I have a display monitor/computer connected to my PC. Is it possible for Javascript to detect the machine connected to my PC and display a specific webpage on this secondary  machine?

The reason I need it is because when JS detects some condition on my PC, it should open up a page on a specific machine connected to my PC.

Would be grateful for any help!!

Comment: From the browser this is not possible (AFAIK). You can only check size of the current window using `window.outer[Width/Height]`

Comment: Maybe you should try : window.screen.availHeight / Width to check some criteria.

Comment: That would return the height of my PC screen, right?

Comment: The simple answer is no, it's not possible.

Comment: That said, it *might* be possible depending on the setup and what kind of preparations you can or are willing to do. For example, the web page can open a popup window that you then drag to the secondary monitor. The original web page can then use this window to display whatever you need.

Comment: No, actually I directly cannot interact with the secondary monitor. The event has to fire on the other machine without any user interaction as such.

Comment: Then you're out of luck, sorry.

Comment: OK, but is there any other way by which a webpage can be opened on another connected machine as an event?

Comment: What do you mean connected machine? Can you use simple widely-understood terms? Ie. Computer, monitor, etc? And connected by what, ethernet, wifi, power cable?